# Referring to Workbook Names

Tags: excel, reference, vba

I have a trouble connected with getting name of `Workbook` object by given reference (`RefersTo`). Code below:

```
Sub add()

  ThisWorkbook.Names.add Name:="Letee", RefersTo:="Nazwa2"
  MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Names(RefersTo:="Nazwa2")

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Why the "MsgBox" line doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure ***Nazwa2*** is a valid Name:

```
Sub add()

Sheets(1).Range("A1").Name = "Nazwa2"
ThisWorkbook.Names.add Name:="Letee", RefersTo:="Nazwa2"
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Names(1)

End Sub
```

To see the chain of names:

```
Sub addx()

    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Name = "Nazwa2"
    ThisWorkbook.Names.add Name:="Letee", RefersTo:="Nazwa2"

    i = 1
    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
         Cells(i, 1).Value = nm.Name
         Cells(i, 2).Value = "'" & nm.RefersTo
     i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's a valid name. Typing the index of name of the workbook instead of RefersTo argument helped. Thank you.